# Historical evidence for Abraham

Tags: tanach, avot-patriarch-fathers

According to prof. John Huddleston there is **no historical evidence** of Abraham from The Genesis. Here is the video. He spokes about it in the first 2-3 minutes: http://youtu.be/21NoQuKTB8Q

Is that true?

Comment: In this past week's covenant and conversation, --  http://www.chiefrabbi.org/2013/06/17/covenant-conversation-balak-the-hardest-word-to-hear/#.UcZTzcfr2c1 -- Rabbi Sacks says "A plaster inscription on the wall of a temple at Deir Alla in Jordan was found to make reference to the night vision of a seer called Bilaam – the earliest reference in archaeological sources to a named individual in the Torah. Thus, though the story itself contains elements of parable, it belongs to a definite context in time and place."

Comment: As far as I am aware there is indeed no archaeological evidence of Avraham's life.

Comment: Why the downvotes? Even Double AA said that it's true and there is no historical evidence for Abraham. Except of the Genesis itself, of course.

Comment: are you asking whether there is extra-biblical corroboration for the existence of personages mentioned in the bible? If so, why focus just on Abraham -- are you saying that there is such corroboration for other people just not Abraham?

Comment: @Danno the vidoe-part is important part of my question. Please, watch it (at least first 3 minutes that are crucial) and only after that give me the answer. Thank you.

Comment: @Derfder I did. This doesn't answer my question -- why are you focusing on Abraham if this video makes the claim that none of the people or events is substantiated by extra-biblical sources?

Comment: Ummm...so everyone-for who knows HOW long?-has been visiting a site that someone just arbitrarily decided to call Abraham and Sarah's graves?? The professor needs a copy of their ketubah, too?

Comment: Humorous sarcastic answers and comments aside, there is currently no evidence of Abraham. What we have is: a. As was pointed out by @Gary, an ages-old tradition of his gravesite. b. Mountains of evidence that the lifestyle of Abraham as described in Genesis accurately represents that of a Patriarchal-era (in archeological terms) wealthy Aramean nomad wandering around Canaan,

Comment: so much so that it would be difficult to imagine that someone many centuries later could have so accurately described such a lifestyle without archeological knowledge (which was practically non-existent until a few centuries ago) or a time machine.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is true. I watched the first 3 minutes (I don't particularly recommend others do so) and can confirm that the person self-identifying as John Huddleston said there is no historical evidence of Abraham from the biblical book of Genesis.

Comment: "I don't particularly recommend others do so" Why not? Are they historically incorrect?

Comment: @Derfder I don't find watching people declare things to be all that interesting.

Comment: So, it's just your personal **subjective** advise to other users? Am I correct? Or did you **objectively** find something what they said to be wrong? If so, what exactly you don't agree?

Comment: @Derfder The parenthetical remark is just my personal advice.

Comment: DoubleAA your advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely false. There is lots of historical evidence, from Genesis, of Abraham, as even a cursory read of Genesis will reveal.

Comment: I am asking for historical evidence. Not Genesis itself. It's obvious that Genesis has this information, because it's from there ;D.

Comment: You said "historical evidence of Abraham from The Genesis".

Comment: I also said: "Here is the video. He spokes about it in the first 2-3 minutes: http://youtu.be/21NoQuKTB8Q ". The video-part is importent part of my question.